# Woocommerce Barn2 Product Table disable product table under categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use the latest version of WordPress and Woocommerce.
I have a plugin Woocommerce Product Table installed. I have no problem with this plugin but cannot customize it at all. by default, it shows all the categories but below that, it shows the product table.

Now, this is my situation I would like to show the product table only in the category that has products in it.

This is how it shows now at this stage.

Main Category-> Sub Cat1 & Sub Cat2 with the product table of both subcategories products in it.

I would like it to be this way around:

Main Cat -> Sub Cat1 -> Then Product Table

Main Cat -> Sub Cat2 -> The Product Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after Long hours searching and testing, I got it to work.

The Template_Handler.php Page needs to be edited. this folder can be found inside plugin folder/ woocommerce-product-table/includes/ you will find the file Template_Handler.php

around line 55/56 add the following code

```
/**HERE IS THE EDIT SCRIPT TO HIDE [product_table] from main categories**/
if ( !is_product_category( array( 'your category 1', 'your category 2', 'your category 3') ) ) {
```

then at the end of the page add

```
}
```

That is it, not the best but it works, Hopes this helps someone else